# IntelliJ IDEA 9 and Scala 2.8

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, scala-2.8

I have a problem with IntelliJ IDEA 9.0's debugger when I run scala code (scala 2.8).
The problem is that I can't see which *case* is selected in the *match* sentence when I make traces step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the debugger ``jumps'' from one case branch to expression to be matched and back to the next branch subsequently. Do you observe another behaviour?

Ilya

Comment: Yes! There is just one way that I see debugger goes to a expression with in a *case* is if I put a breakpoint in the expression.